# How many types of Buddhism exists in this world?

Tags: theravada, vipassana, tibetan-buddhism, zen

many times, I stumbled to start to dig something towards teaching of Buddha and at some point want to make focus on Buddhism. During my journey of looking bird eye of view, I passed through `Vipassana`, `Therevada`, `Zen`, `Dalai Lama`, `Tibet`, `Nepal` and `Mynmar`. Last read bit about Buddhism in Sri Lanka? How Arthur Schopenhauer inspired himself with Budda? Who guided him or how he came to know about terms like `enlightenment`.?

Answer (score 1):

The world religions tree gives a bird's eye view of the development of all world religions.

https://external-preview.redd.it/e5i27HPcaGrDPApm2lyfRyn3JQlLZV_Ko6mSzmIXa7Y.jpg?auto=webp&s=305e5527d3e7f831b338c26e205840836f26edaf

Answer (score 0):

**During my journey of looking bird eye of view, I passed through `Vipassana`, `Therevada`, `Zen`, `Dalai Lama`, `Tibet`, `Nepal` and `Mynmar`.**

These are different kinds of things:

- **Vipassana** -- means "insight" ... and "Vipassana meditation" refers to forms of meditation, taught by schools, from which practice you're supposed to be able to get insight
- **Therevada** and **Zen** -- these are the names of schools or traditions of Buddhism (though Zen or Zazen meaning "sitting" is also the name of a practice)
- **Dalai Lama** -- this is the title of one of the leaders of Tibetan Buddhism (and refers to the current leader/title-holder)
- **Tibet**, **Nepal** and **Mynmar** -- these are or were mostly-Buddhist countries (though it's reasonable to associate different countries with different schools)

---

**How many types of Buddhism exists in this world?**

People often identify three main types -- see [Schools of Buddhism (Classifications)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schools_of_Buddhism#Classifications) -- i.e. *Theravada*, *Mahayana**, and *Vajrayana*, with different traditions with different countries:

[[image: Buddhist_sects.png][1]]

And there are branches, differences in emphasis or tradition, or of some detail of doctrine or practice, within each school.

Since the 19th century you could add [Western Buddhism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhism_in_the_West) to the list.

---

**Last read bit about Buddhism in Sri Lanka?**

That's one of the Theravada countries.

---

**How Arthur Schopenhauer inspired himself with Budda? Who guided him or how he came to know about terms like `enlightenment`?**

I don't know his work at all.

Note that "enlightenment" is a Western European word, which doesn't exist in Buddhism! It's a word which Westerners use to [translate various Buddhist words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightenment_in_Buddhism) e.g. *Bodhi*, *Vimutti*, or *Satori*.

Students often find it helpful to use some of these original words -- dong that might be more precise in meaning, because other there are several English words that you might could use to translate each Buddhist word.

Wikipedia -- [Arthur Schopenhauer (Buddhism)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Schopenhauer#Buddhism) -- suggests there's not very much connection between Schopenhauer and Buddhism, i.e. that:

- Schopenhauer developed his philosophy independently before he read about Buddhism
- The philosophy which he developed isn't (according to other people) exactly Buddhism, though when he did begin to read about Buddhism Schopenhauer felt that it was like his own philosophy

Comment: If I recall correctly, Schopenhauer learnt about Buddhism from a eurocentric, superficial perspective, which gave him the -wrong- impression that buddhism was a pessimistic philosophy system, which made emphasis on how life is painful and full of suffering; in other words, he only used one of the multuple aspects covered by the concept of dukkha, and by doing that, he misunderstood how the Buddha understood the world.